# After upload photo, how can i retrieve the photo on my apps?

Tags: php, facebook

I am use following methods to upload photo :

```
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
$data = $facebook->api('me/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

After success to upload photo, `$data` return `"Array ( [id] => 1.16874205038E+14 )"`.
How can i access the photo on my apps?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sprintf('%s', $data['id']);
```

With [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) you can ask php to treat long number as a string and after that you can work with that string as you wish.

```
$photo = $facebook->api(sprintf('%s', $data['id']));
```

This will return an array of your photo details. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo

PS: i'm not sure if you need an implicit casting to string in this particular case, so you can try to get the `$photo` with or without `sprintf`.

Comment: Hi zerkms, thank for your help, I am fix it by used normal facebook acc. But it still error on my facebook test acc.